# Parallelizing a library with lots of global variables

Tags: c++, qt

I'm currently using QT (4) to parallelize a non-threadsafe library that's written in C by non-programmers, and thus has a lot of global variables. The threads don't need to interact or share data, they each just call a bunch of methods of the library and then at the end the library gives an output that is used further.

The problem is, though, that global variables are per default shared between threads, causing the library to crash in different places. There are two ways to fix this:

Refactor the entire library to not use global variables (ouch), or find a way to make global variables non-shared, or find a third magic way.

Is the latter an option with QT or standard (C++01) C++?

Comment: Are you converting the library to C++ code? If so, would it work if you wrapped it inside a C++ class, and made global variables into class member variables (and any variables which actually are shared can be made static member variables, and if not const then to be protected by mutexes).

Comment: @hyde: What you're suggesting would probably work. I could even make a giant superhack, where I #include the files into each other so that the entire codebase is one templated .h at the end with everything else inside it. I don't want to do it if I can get around it, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using thread local storage is a way to make global variables non-shared. Starting point for that, with links to details for different implementations:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage

Answer (score 1):

You can't "unshare" global variables. The only available option for parallelization  (bar refactoring) is to have multiple processes instead of multiple threads. Preferably pooled.

Comment: I'd agree on this, you can just used shared memory between the worker processes and the main one to do all the communication you now do with your threads and be safe with the global variables since each process will have it's own instance of the library.

Comment: Problem is, the parallelization environment I'm using is a pre-existing, proprietary one. I can't just change it, since a couple dozen people in my department depend on it, and someone else is maintaining and coding it. So my only option is probably to dive in and refactor the library. :_-(

Answer (score 0):

Create a singleton that is responsible for synchronizing the access to the global variables. The global variables become members of the new singleton class and can be accessed by methods that have the same names as your current global variables so you don't need to change code all over the place.